# Verify Soap message signature without handler

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soaphandler

I have some problem with Soaphandler for signature verification. Is there any way to catch to soapmessage or any way to verify Soapmessage signature without handler?

Comment: do you have a wsdl file?

Comment: yes, i have wsdl file and generating my service from it.